# Humongous.io connection to AWS ec2 mongo

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, server

I was unable to connect to my running Mongo daemon on ec2 instance of AWS
When I ssh into the instance and enter

```
mongo
```

It runs perfectly. However trying to connect the Mongo via Humongous.io

```
mongo://user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/db-name
```

Whitelist the ip address 52.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the ec2 instance

Once you have mongo downloaded, installed - It creates mongod.conf and mongodb.conf files in /etc (Ubuntu/Fedora or Linux distro)

Change the

```
net
 bind:127.0.0.1
 port:27017
```

To

```
net
 bind:0.0.0.0
 port:27017
```

In both mongod.conf and mongodb.conf

Restart the mongo server
    sudo service mongod restart

Error would be resolved